# Unstacking json dictionaries in pandas

Tags: python, json, pandas, dictionary, json-normalize

I've got one for ya.

So I'm trying to unpack some proprietary data I'm getting from an api.

for a reproducible example once I unpack the json data, I get a dictionary that looks like this

```
temp = ([{"date" : "12/15/2020","order_id" : 1, "order_items" : [{"name" : "sponge", "quantity" : 2},{"name" : "soap", "quantity" : 17}]},
 {"date" : "12/14/2020","order_id" : 2, "order_items" : [{"name" : "soap", "quantity" : 4}]}]
)
```

I then make a dataframe using this code

```
df = pd.json_normalize(temp)
```

now what this gives me is a dataframe that looks kind of like this.

```
what_i_have = pd.DataFrame({
"date" : ["12/15/2020","12/14/2020"],
"order_id" : [1,2],
"order_items" : [[{'name' : 'sponge', 'quantity' : 2},{'name' : 'soap', 'quantity' : 17}],[{'name' : 'sponge', 'quantity' : 4}]]
})
```

Now, I see that the problem is that when I used json_normalize it didn't go down enough levels.
If I do something like

```
pd.json_normalize(df['order_items'][0])
```

it returns to me a 2 row, 2 column dataframe.
if I do

```
df['order_items'] = df['order_items'].apply(lambda x: pd.json_normalize(x))
```

I get a dataframe that has dataframe objects in the order_items column, that I can't quite figure out how to use.

What I want to do is to unpack the tables I make at the lower level, and make my dataframe longer. I want it to look like this

```
what_i_want = pd.DataFrame({
"date" : ["12/15/2020","12/15/2020","12/14/2020"],
"order_id" : [1,1,2],
"order_items.name" : ["sponge","soap","soap"],
"order_items.quantity" : [2,17,4]
})
```

Any suggestions on how to do that?

ps. I think the reason that json_normalize doesn't go down enough levels is because the order_items has a varying length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The other parameters for [`pandas.json_normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html) must be used to correctly unpack the data.

```py
import pandas as pd

# sample data
temp = [{'date': '12/15/2020', 'order_id': 1, 'order_items': [{'name': 'sponge', 'quantity': 2}, {'name': 'soap', 'quantity': 17}]}, {'date': '12/14/2020', 'order_id': 2, 'order_items': [{'name': 'soap', 'quantity': 4}]}]

# unpack temp using the other parameters
df = pd.json_normalize(data=temp, record_path=['order_items'], meta=['date', 'order_id'])

# display(df)
     name  quantity        date order_id
0  sponge         2  12/15/2020        1
1    soap        17  12/15/2020        1
2    soap         4  12/14/2020        2
```